# ¿Trabajar con un archivo xlsx sin que se abra excel en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo este codigo para obtener la primera celde del un archovo de .xlsx

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        string workbookPath = "c:/Libro1.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

        string currentSheet = "Hoja1";
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet); //en esta instruccion me sale la excepcion
        Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");




        string str = (excelCell.Cells as Excel.Range).Value2;

        MessageBox.Show(str);
```

pero en cuanto lo ejecuto me abre la hoja con excel, hay alguna manera de trabajar con el archivo sin que se abra el programa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No recomiendo que uses las librerias COM de Office para trabjar el documento, son para problema.
Utiliza librerias basadas en `open xml`

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

en el documentacion explica como acceder a las celdas de forma muy simple, es mas no tendras que tener instalado office para operar con el excel.

**>>pero en cuanto lo ejecuto me abre la hoja con excel**

Debes definir la propiedad

```
excelApp.Visible = false;
```

si defines que sea visible se mostrara la aplicacion

Comment: Coincido con Leandro en la recomendación de no usar las librerías COM de Office!

Comment: no me reconoce XLWorkbook(); del primer ejemplo

Comment: estas agregando la referencia a la libreria ClosedXml, puedes hacerlo usando nuger  https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML  recuerda tambien definir el using

Answer (score 1):

Yo he trabajado con la librería EPPlus con muy buenos resultados. La podés instalar en Visual Studio desde este enlace:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Esta librería no abrirá la aplicación Excel ni necesita que se encuentre instalado.

Podés encontrar más información en http://epplus.codeplex.com/

En particular en este enlace podés ver qué soporta y qué no soporta: http://epplus.codeplex.com/documentation

Espero que te sirva.