# ¿Cómo saber el número de filas que tiene un archivo xlsx en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy ocupando este código para obtener la primer celda del archivo

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        string workbookPath = "c:/Users/Edgar/Desktop/base/Libro1.xlsx";//‪C:\Users\Edgar\Desktop\base\Libro1.xlsx
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, true, 0, true, false, false);
        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
        excelApp.Visible = false;
        string currentSheet = "Hoja1";
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);







        Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        string str = (excelCell.Cells as Excel.Range).Value2;

        MessageBox.Show(str);
```

pero quiero guardar en una variable el número de filas que están llenas en xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que no seguiste el consejo de la otra pregunta

[¿Trabajar con un archivo xlsx sin que se abra excel en c#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17237/trabajar-con-un-archivo-xlsx-sin-que-se-abra-excel-en-c)

en donde recomendamos usar alguna libreria basada en open xml

**>>quiero guardar en una variable el número de filas que están llenas en xlsx**

Podrias utilizar

[Worksheet.UsedRange Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx)

entonces harias

```
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

int rCnt = range.Rows.Count;
```